# Is there a way to axiomatize the category of sets and relations?

Tags: category-theory, axioms, foundations

The system of axioms known as [ETCS](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ETCS) axiomatizes the category of sets and functions. Does anyone know of a way to axiomatize the category (and/or allegory) of sets and **relations**?

Answer (score 5):

From *Categories, Allegories* by Freyd, Scedrov:

> **2.414**. If $\mathbf{C}$ is a topos, then $\mathscr{Rel}(\mathbf{C})$ is a power allegory. Conversely, if $\mathbf{A}$ is a unitary tabular power allegory, then $\mathscr{Map}(\mathbf{A})$ is a topos.

So a reasonable approach would be to start with "$\mathbf{A}$ unitary tabular power allegory", then translate well-pointed, NNO, and AC into the allegory language.

Answer (score -2):

Here's one way presented in at least one publication:

Objects are pairs $(X,\rho)$ with $X$ a set and $\rho \subset X \times X $ is a relation on $X$.

For a pair of objects $(X,\rho)$ and $(Y,\sigma)$, arrows are maps $f: X \to Y$ that preserve the relation, ie, $x_1 \rho x_2 \implies f(x_1) \sigma f(x_2)$ for $x_1, x_2 \in X$. (Are arrows set functions or relations?)

(Further, there is an induced relation between parallel pairs of arrows but I'll have to recall the details)

This is for example exactly how Schreider and Sossinsky defines the category of tolerance spaces, ie, sets with a reflexive, symmetric relation on them.

Note the relations here are not general:

(1) the relations are binary

(2) are "endo" since they're defined *on* the set $X$, as opposed to relating distinct sets ($\xi \subset X \times Y$)

(3) are 2-valued.

I don't know if considering arrows that *reflect* relation rather than *preserve* it is still the same category (dualized).

Also you wrote "axiomatize" so I think this answer suffices. If you has asked for basic properties such as what limits exist, that's another story...

Comment: I think this is a construction, not an axiomatization. An axiomatization would describe a list of properties. Also, this isn't the category of relations.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, (1) the cat I described is called $\bf Rel$ in the publication that I based my answer on (can email you the photo in my iPhone but there's no biblio info). If this is not the "category of sets and relations" what's the diff and relationship between them? (2) Isn't axiomatization just definition?

Comment: This is nonstandard. One paper does not determine standard usage. In standard usage, $\text{Rel}$ is the category whose objects are sets and whose morphisms are relations, with composition given by relational composition. What you describe is more like the category of graphs. An axiomatization of a thing should describe a list of axioms satisfied by that thing, e.g. we can axiomatize the natural numbers using the axioms of Peano arithmetic (which does not give a construction of the natural numbers; in fact Peano arithmetic has many models that aren't the usual natural numbers).